# Locating sublists of one list in another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `G3, G333`. I want to locate the sublists of `G333` in `G3` and print the indices `i`. For example, `[0, 4, 5, 9]` occurs at `i=0` in `G3`, `[10, 14, 15, 19]` occurs at `i=5` in `G3`. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
G3=[[0, 4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10], [2, 6, 7, 11], [3, 7, 8, 12], [9, 13, 14, 18], [10, 14, 15, 19]]

G333=[[0, 4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10], [10, 14, 15, 19]] 


G3s = set(map(tuple, G3))
G333s = set(map(tuple, G333)) 

for i in range(0,len(G3s)): 
    if (G3s[i] & G333s[i]): 
        print(i)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    if (G3s[i] & G333s[i]):

TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output is

```
i=[0,1,5]
```

Comment: `set` is unordered..! you can't compare index while having `set()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `list.index` to get the index.

```py
for l in G333:
    print(G3.index(l))
```

Or, with a list comprehension:

```py
i = [G3.index(l) for l in G333] # [0, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```py
G3 = [
    [0, 4, 5, 9],
    [1, 5, 6, 10],
    [2, 6, 7, 11],
    [3, 7, 8, 12],
    [9, 13, 14, 18],
    [10, 14, 15, 19],
]

G333 = [[0, 4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10], [10, 14, 15, 19]]


for idx, sublist in enumerate(G3):
    if sublist in G333:
        print(idx)
```

The above solution uses `enumerate` to iterate through `G3` members, while also retrieving each element from `G3` to compare with the sub-lists from
`G333`.

If you want to use the same approach as your current solution, you could
use something like:

```py
G3 = [
    [0, 4, 5, 9],
    [1, 5, 6, 10],
    [2, 6, 7, 11],
    [3, 7, 8, 12],
    [9, 13, 14, 18],
    [10, 14, 15, 19],
]

G333 = [[0, 4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10], [10, 14, 15, 19]]

G3s = set(map(tuple, G3))
G333s = set(map(tuple, G333))

for element in G333s & G3s:
    print(G3.index(list(element)))
```

However, I personally find the first option to be easier to understand and use.

---

**Side-note:** when using `for...loops`, avoid using `i` as name for the elements of your iterator. Rather, try names that better explain what each element represents. For iterating through indexes, for example, I prefer using the name `idx` (it's a common shorthand for index).

Answer (score 0):

You can use index function and if any item is missing that can be handled like below:

```
G3=[[0, 4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10], [2, 6, 7, 11], [3, 7, 8, 12], [9, 13, 14, 18], [10, 14, 15, 19]]

G333=[[0, 4, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 10], [10, 14, 15, 19]] 

i = []

for item in G333:
    try:
        i.append(G3.index(item))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(i)
```